# If I install a desktop environment in Ubuntu, will applications automatically use it?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop

If I am in Ubuntu server and I install a desktop environment like GNOME from apt, if I run firefox, does it automatically know to use that desktop environment, or do I have to configure my environment so that it does?

Comment: You've been able to run firefox in a console?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never had to configure anything additional to get the web browser to work. You should just have to install `tasksel`, pick your gui interface, and then install your display manager.

This works because `tasksel` will also install the other required packages to ensure the gui will be fully featured.

My personal DM preference is `lightdm` with the Mate Core gui, but you can use anything listed in `tasksel`.

Here's a link to a decent tutorial: https://itsfoss.com/install-gui-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to do this as simply as possible. I installed GNOME from apt but I don’t see anything in my VNC server. I don’t know how to launch it. I know VNC is working because DISPLAY:1 firefox shows it in my VNC.

Comment: if you dont have the gui interface up yet you'll need to start the gui service. as long as you have the display manager installed you should be able to start the service with ```sudo service (insert displaymanager here) start``` this should launch your gui on the host machine.

Comment: So to go from Ubuntu Server to launching a desktop environment in the most minimalistic way possible requires me to install a display manager beyond all else? The display manager connects the GUI to the display - but we install the GUI separately? So you can’t launch a GUI on its own, it has to be launched by the DM?

Comment: Correct Ubuntu server by itself does not have a gui, you know this of course. Because of this it does not have a native display manager built into it so you need to install one to be able to run your gui of choice. ```sudo apt install slim``` or ```sudo apt install lightdm``` im sure there are others but these are the two I have used. If you already have the GUI installed the display manager should grab it and launch it.